# Retrieve the X & Y coordinates of a button in android?

Tags: android, button, position

I've been working on Android for a while and would like to know if it is possible to retrieve the position of a button in android.

My target is to get the X & Y coordinates and print them on the LOGCAT.

Some example to show me how would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure, you can get these, make sure the views are drawn atleast once before you try to get the positions. You could try to get the positions in onResume() and try these functions

```
view.getLocationInWindow()
or
view.getLocationOnScreen()
```

or if you need something relative to the parent, use

```
view.getLeft(), view.getTop()
```

Links to API definitions:

- [getLocationInWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationInWindow%28int%5B%5D%29)
- [getLocationOnScreen](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationOnScreen%28int%5B%5D%29)
- [getLeft](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLeft%28%29)
- [getTop](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTop%28%29)

Comment: **getLocationInWindow(int[])** and **getLocationOnScreen(int[])** has parameter. Are you sure about your idea?

Comment: @hakkikonu take a look to my answer to understand the usage of **getLocationInWindow(int[])**.

Answer (score 11):

Like [Azlam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13046/azlam) said you can use [View.getLocationInWindow()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationInWindow(int[])) to get the **coordinates x,y**.

Here is an example:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourButtonId);
Point point = getPointOfView(button);
Log.d(TAG, "view point x,y (" + point.x + ", " + point.y + ")");

private Point getPointOfView(View view) {
    int[] location = new int[2];
    view.getLocationInWindow(location);
    return new Point(location[0], location[1]);
}
```

**Bonus** - To get the center point of the given view:

```
Point centerPoint = getCenterPointOfView(button);
Log.d(TAG, "view center point x,y (" + centerPoint.x + ", " + centerPoint.y + ")");

private Point getCenterPointOfView(View view) {
    int[] location = new int[2];
    view.getLocationInWindow(location);
    int x = location[0] + view.getWidth() / 2;
    int y = location[1] + view.getHeight() / 2;
    return new Point(x, y);
}
```

I hope the example can still be useful to someone.

Answer (score 2):

```
buttonObj.getX();
buttonObj.getY();
```