# Get parameters of relative layout in android

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-button

In android , i am creating a button in relative layout.i want to know the x and y possition of button

`button_open=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_alert);
        button_x=button_open.getX();
        button_y=button_open.getY();`

but i get 0.0, 0.0 respectivelyt for the floating variables button_x,button_y.

Answer (score 1):

try below way to achieve your goal:-

```
view.getLocationInWindow()
```

or

```
view.getLocationOnScreen()
```

for more info see below link:-

[Retrieve the X & Y coordinates of a button in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203740/retrieve-the-x-y-coordinates-of-a-button-in-android)

Comment: thanx,but it return 0

Comment: @JithinMechery view ?

Comment: May be the problem due to calling getLocation() function before the button is load.So Which function i can use to listen or that function which will call my instruction after loading the view.

Comment: view is your button view

Answer (score 0):

you should give the system the time to measure/layout the object. View can either register a [ViewTreeObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html), or post a runnable on the root layout and retrieve those information when the runnable is executed