# Retrieve the X & Y of FAB

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view, floating-action-button

I have a RelativeLayout and inside this layout i have fab button:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"/>
```

Now , in java I want to now, where is the fab position on the screen.I used this method according this post : [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203740/retrieve-the-x-y-coordinates-of-a-button-in-android)

```
private Point getPointOfView(View view) {
    int[] location = new int[2];
    view.getLocationInWindow(location);
    return new Point(location[0], location[1]);
}
```

and using this method like this:

```
fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
for (int i = 0; i < pv.length; i++) {
    pv[i] = new Point(getPointOfView(fab).x ,getPointOfView(fab).y);
}
```

but `getPointOfView(fab).x and getPointOfView(fab).y` return 0.how could i retrieve the X & Y fab button?

Comment: Why down Vote? some people just know down vote instead of helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `View#post()` API, then your code would be replaced with this one:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // this callback will be executed after view is laid out
        for (int i = 0; i < pv.length; ++i) {
            pv[i] = new Point(getPointOfView(fab).x ,getPointOfView(fab).y);
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: dude,`fab.post`execute command into ui thread.What is difference between execute this command in oncreate and without post?@azizbekian

Comment: In `onCreate()` your view hierarchy hasn't yet been laid out, thus it will return zeros.

Comment: Ok,but `fab.post` is waiting to view is created? like `addOnGlobalLayoutListener`

Comment: Yes, `View#post()` will defer an action to be performed after view is laid out some time later.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
View.getLocationOnScreen()
```

method to get values.
Note: try to use this method in handler

```
new Handler ().post(...... v.getLocationOnScreen(location); .....);
```

onCreate method is to early to get location we should have to try this in `onWindowFocusChanged()` method of activity when application end all the view related tasks.

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13244091/6236752)

Comment: I have changed my method to `view.getLocationOnScreen(location);` but returned 0 for x and y again

Comment: I have changed my method: `private Point getPointOfView(final View view) {
        final int[] location = new int[2];
        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
            }
        });
        return new Point(location[0], location[1]);
    }` I got 0

Comment: activity also have this paste this code inside your activity. @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        if(!hasFocus) {
            //do anything you want here
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Activity changed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

Comment: dude, when activity is up this method not called but i want to get fab position at first time when activity is up.this method not called first.I have just one activity

Answer (score 0):

I found, how could i get fab position:

```
fab.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        for (int i = 0; i < pv.length; i++) {
            pv[i] = new Point(getPointOfView(fab).x, getPointOfView(fab).y);
        }
        fab.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
    }
});
```

but if i have mistake in removing GloabalLayout place please tel me.